# Axios does not send credentials in the browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

this is the url i'm making a get request to:

> https://crayonnne-jotter-server.herokuapp.com/api/note/get/all/62c6f10051ed8331aaa69562

Everything works fine in Postman, but it brings "unauthenticated user" in the browser even when i specified withCredentials: true.
that's the error I set in the server side when a user is trying to reach any endpoint without an accessToken.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an Authorization section in the header of your request. your header should look like:

`{Authorization: 'Bearer TOKEN_GOES_HERE'}`